# Calculate the accurate x and y position of a div inside a rotated div

Tags: html, canvas, rotation, transformation

I've implemented a zoom and crop on the HTML5 Canvas. Zoom is actually increasing the height and width of the Canvas so that it looks zoomed. For crop, I wrote an algorithm to select a rectangular area using mouse and then crop it. Now, if I want to crop when the image is zoomed in or out, while selecting the crop area I have to consider the top and left position displacement caused due to the zoom , which works fine.

So I'm now implementing a rotate (using css3 transform: rotate). The problem is, when I rotate the image by a certain angle, the selection appears a little away from the actual mouse position. This used to happen for the zoom effect as well, but since I used to subtract the added left and top distance from the x and y position resp., I was able to draw the selection even when the image was zoomed. I don't understand how I should do it for a rotated image!

The following image might help you understand my problem a little more clearly:

[image: Selection issue when rotated]

There's a div around the canvas, reflecting the canvas. It'll have the same width, height, top, left properties as the canvas. This is done on purpose since I can't add the selection, which is absolute, as the child of the canvas. Now this cover, when selected in FireBug, still shows as a rectangle with increased width and height and changed top and left positions.

I understand I have to calculate the displacement like I'm already doing for zoom, but I don't know how to do it! I have spent a lot of time trying out stuff like Pythagoras algorithm and rotational matrix and blah blah!

Please help me out!

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate each of the vertices using this function where "pnt" is a vertex, "pivot" is the point you're rotating around and "angle" is the angle in radians

```
function rotatePoint(pnt, pivot, angle){
   var data = figureAngle(pivot, pnt),
      theta = data.angle + angle,
      rise = Math.sin(theta) * data.length,
      run = Math.cos(theta) * data.length;

   return {
      x: pivot.x + run,
      y: pivot.y + rise
   }
}

function figureAngle(start, end){
   var rise = (end.y - start.y),
        run = (end.x - start.x),
        length = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(rise, 2) + Math.pow(run, 2));

   return {length: length, angle: Math.atan2(-rise, -run) + Math.PI};
}
```

Then your horizontal shift is going to be the smallest x of the 4 new vertices, and your vertical shift is going to be the smallest y.

EDIT: this assumes your top left coordinate is [0, 0] before you rotate. If not you need to subtract your starting coordinates from the results i.e. if your top-left corner starts at [50, 100], your horizontal shift would be xMin - 50, and your vertical would be yMin - 100

Comment: I'm using the rotate transformation, hence I think the pivot is the center of the image. Also, will I have to do this for all the 4 corners of the selection?

Comment: No, I guess you mean the x and y co ords of the mouse click... right?

Comment: If css rotates from the middle of the rectangle, then yes pivot would be the center of the rectangle, and yes you need to run that function for each corner of the rectangle. You'll end up with the coordinates of the new corners of the rotated rectangle.

Comment: I'm confused! What is `figureAngle` and where does `data.angle` come from? Also, each point is a set of x and y co ords... how am I supposed to substitute them in your function?

Comment: Oops, sorry copied that from some of my code, I forgot it has dependencies. Updating

Comment: in my function the points are represented by {x: integer, y: integer} objects, you could either edit the functions to accept more parameters, or use array. It's just a preference thing.